# Difference in speed computation between STL vector of vectors and contiguous storage

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

In my program i have to scroll a lot of time a 2d array and do  some computation over it;
In a first way i saved my matrix as a `vector<vector<int>>;`.
After i tried with a contiguous memory 2d array

```
template <typename T>
T** create2DArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols)
{
   T** ptr = new T*[nrows];  // allocate pointers
   T* pool = new T[nrows*ncols];  // allocate pool
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i, pool += ncols )
       ptr[i] = pool;
   return ptr;
}

template <typename T>
void delete2DArray(T** arr)
{
   delete [] arr[0];  // remove the pool
   delete [] arr;     // remove the pointers
}

int main()
{ 
   double **dPtr = create2DArray<double>(10,10);
   dPtr[0][0] = 10;  // for example
   delete2DArray(dPtr);  // free the memory
}
```

And i saw that with a vector of vectors storaging my computation speed is more or less two time faster than contiguous way.I don't understand why.

EDIT :I have a matrix of integer made by 0,1,2 and I have to read a file in which is stored a matrix with cars (*1=BlueCar, 2=RedCar, 0=Empty*).

I need to **write an algorithm to move the cars** of the matrix in that way:

- blue ones move *downward*;
- red ones move *rightward*;
- there is a *turn* in which all the blue ones move and a turn to move all the red ones.

I have two vectors that have the coordinates of non 0 cell of the matrix,and i scroll the matrix through these vectors.
So i have to access a lot of time to this matrix and change it.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the computation in question? The access pattern is particularly important. (If you're measuring the time for that single assignment, I don't believe your measurements - the time that takes will be dwarfed by allocation and deallocation and lost in the noise.)

Comment: @AlanStokes  i tried to explain in easy way what i have to do.